# Overloading '=' in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, operator-overloading, equals-operator

Since simply overloading `'='` in Perl does not act as one would expect, what is the proper way to do this?

Quote from [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Overloadable-Operations) perldoc:

> Simple assignment is not overloadable (the `'='` key is used for the Copy Constructor). Perl does have a way to make assignments to an object do whatever you want, but this involves using `tie()`, not `overload` - see [tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) and the [COOKBOOK](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#COOKBOOK) examples below.

I have read through the [COOKBOOK](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#COOKBOOK) and the documentation for [tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) and am having trouble figuring out how you could use it in this way.

---

I want to be able to create an object like so: `my $object = Object->new()` Then when I assign it to something I want it to do some special processing.

For example: `$object = 3` would internally do something like `$object->set_value(3);`

**I know this isn't necessarily good practice.  This is more of an educational question.  I just want to know *how* this can be done.  Not whether it *should* be done.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. You can add magic to a variable so that a sub is called after a value is assigned to the variable, but that's a far cry from what you asked.

---

Besides, what you asked doesn't really make sense. What should the following do?

```
my $object;
$object = Object->new();
$object = Object->new();
```

Comment: If it's not possible, then what does the documentation mean by this? "Perl does have a way to make assignments to an object do whatever you want, but this involves using tie(), not overload."

Comment: `tie` more-or-less exposes magic to Perl code. You can tie a variable so that a sub is called after a value is assigned to the variable, but that's a far cry from what you asked. As I pointed out, what you asked doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: The code you wrote above would create a new object with the first `new` call, then would set the value of that object to another instance of the object with the second call.

Comment: The second call would work like `$object->set_value(Object->new())`

Comment: Not that that's useful, but i would assume that would be how it would work if it was set up that way.

Comment: Why would the same code do something vastly different the second time around? What if I wanted to replace the value of `$object` both times? Your answer to my rhetorical question proves my point: What you asked doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The perl documentation quoted above is somewhat poorly worded. There is no way to overload assignment into some storage location (i.e. variable) that currently contains some specific object or other; the current value of a variable is never important for assignment.

However, what you can do is add magic to that variable directly, that captures the attempt to store into it (`SET` magic, implemented by the `STORE` method of the tied class). But it is important to realise this is magic on the variable itself, and not the value that it currently contains.